# Запросы MySQL и C++

Tags: sql, c++, mysql

Всем привет. Например, у меня есть бд - "baza", в ней следующая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE
        `tab` (
            `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `name` CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            `hash` blob NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
        )
```

В эту таблицу вносятся данные:

```
INSERT INTO
        `tab` (`name`, `hash`)
    VALUES
        ('nature', 48847E5536130C10)
```

Как сделать на C++ процедуру, триггер или обычный запрос, который будет добавлять в таблицу - "tab" данные, но перед этим будет проверять 3-е поле в этой таблице. Т.е. если в таблице уже есть такое значение хеша (которое пытается добавится), то этот инсерт нужно пропустить. Делаю все под linux, так и не нашел, как нормально запросы писать, из того что усвоил написал программу, но даже этот запрос не отрабатывает, т.к. насколько я понял, он используется для разного рода статических действий.

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void mysql(const char query[])
{
    MYSQL mysql;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_FIELD *field;

    char host[] = "127.0.0.1";
    char user[] = "root";
    char passwd[] = "";
    char db[] = "baza";
    int port = 0;

    mysql_init(&mysql);
    mysql_real_connect(&mysql, host, user, passwd, db, port, NULL, 0);

    if (mysql_query(&mysql, query) > 0) {
        printf("%s", mysql_error(&mysql));
        return;
    }

    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(&mysql);
}

int main()
{
    char a = 5;
    char b = 5;

    mysql("INSERT INTO tab VALUES(" ' " + a + "', '" + b + "' ")");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я не понял - а кто будет экранировать символы? Си считает, что \" - окончание строки. Т.е. парсер поисковый запрос явно некорректно отрабатывает. Чтобы ввести запрещенные символы их экранируют, т.е. чтобы пропечатать \" в строчке Си, нужно ввести обратную косую черту как \\"

Answer (score 2):

У вас тут и без этого куча ошибок :)

1)

```
('nature', 48847E5536130C10)
```

Что это вставляется в blob? Зачем для хэша вообще blob (наверняка это int)?

2) 
    mysql_free_result(res);

Что передаётся в res? Переменная не инициализирована никак.

3)

```
 mysql("INSERT INTO tab VALUES("' " + a + "', '" + b + "' ")");
```

Для начала хорошо бы почитать про работу со строками в C, что здесь написано даже не должно компилироваться.